# Magento 2.3 - Change the Contact page success message

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, contact-us, contact-form

I want to change the Success Message in the Contact Page. After someone press the submit button the Success page is like this:

[image]

How I can to change the Success Page to display a static block for example or to be something like this:

[image]

Comment: @GosuPrzmak you have read my post? I ask about Contact Success page, what you send me is about Order Success page, this two things are very very different.

Comment: my bad robert i will take a look tomorrow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for your requirement you need to overwrite the Magento_Contact Post controller. By default Magento_Contact module redirects to `contact/index` after you submit the Contact Form. Follow these steps to overwrite.

Added to your custom module di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post" type="[Name Space]\[Your Module]\Controller\Contact\Post" />
```

Create the custom controller class

```
<?php

namespace [Name Space]\[Your Module]\Controller\Contact\Post;

class Post extends \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post

{

public function execute($coreRoute = null)

{

    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }
    try {
        $this->sendEmail($this->validatedParams());
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
            __('Thanks for contacting us with your comments and questions. We\'ll respond to you very soon.')
        );        
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());     
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->critical($e);
        $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
            __('An error occurred while processing your form. Please try again later.')
        );      
    }
    return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('<Your Module Frontend Page Path>');

}     
}
```

"***Your Module Frontend Page Path***" something like custom-module/success

Refer the class for details.

> /vendor/magento/module-contact/Controller/Index/Post.php

By overwriting the execute function you re-direct to the new custom page template.

**How to create a Custom Page**

Please check [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html).

Hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer, I have a request to you, can you add the code how we can do the redirect, because in fact this is my question, to overwrite a module I know but I want to know how I can made that redirect to a new .phtml or static block, thank you in advance

Comment: @Robert updated please have a look now.

Comment: thank you very much, can you tell me please how this code redirect the success page to a static block?

Comment: If you using the default contact form page then this overwrite controller will handle the post form request. At first it will do all the necessary stuff of sending email or any error message. Then last line of the function will redirect to your Custom Page which is loading the static block. @Robert